# how to display julia Gadfly plot in atom editor?

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

```
using Gadfly 
xvalues = rand(1000);
yvalues = rand(1000);
Gadfly.plot(x=xvalues,y=xvalues,Geom.point,Geom.line)
```

I am trying make a plot using julia Gadfly package in the atom editor . it does display any plot in the plot panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have been fixed by [GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/pull/1373](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/pull/1373) (in Gadfly v1.2). What version of Gadfly do you have?:

```
julia> ]st Gadfly
```

If you have an older version, try doing `popdisplay()`, and redoing the plot.

Comment: thank you it, worked for me. I am trying to do inside atom editor.